# too many arguments error in dev-c++

Tags: c++, arguments

This is a program that I've been working on for a school project of mine.I'm getting an error that I don't really understand.I'm using Bloodshed Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 and the error I'm getting is "In function 'voidCaesar()' too many arguments to function 'int esteLitera()' at this point in file"(referring to line 55).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void afisareMeniu();
void criptCaesar();
void criptMansfield();
void decriptTranspozitie();
int esteLitera(char);

#define CRIPTCAESAR 1
#define CRIPTMANSFIELD 2
#define DECRIPTTRANSPOZITIE 3
#define IESIRE 4
int main()
{
 int nrOptiune;
 for(;;){
         afisareMeniu();
         std::cout<<endl<<"\n\n\n";
         cin>>nrOptiune;
         if(nrOptiune==CRIPTCAESAR)criptCaesar();
         if(nrOptiune==CRIPTMANSFIELD)criptMansfield();
         if(nrOptiune==DECRIPTTRANSPOZITIE)decriptTranspozitie();
         if(nrOptiune==IESIRE)break;
         }//for
         return 0;
}//int main
void afisareMeniu()
{
system("cls");
cout<<"\n Proiect Programarea Calculatoarelor"<<endl<<"Calculatoare 1.1.1";
cout<<"\n\n 1.Criptare Caesar"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\n 2.Criptare Mansfield"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\n 3.Decriptare prin transpozitie cu 2 jumatati"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\n 4.Iesire"<<endl;
}
void criptCaesar()
{
 system("cls");
 cout<<"\n\n Ati ales criptare Caesar"<<endl;
 char s1[100];
 char s2[100];
 cout<<"\n\n Introduceti textul pentru criptare"<<endl;
 cin.get();
 cin.get(s1,100);
 strupr(s1);
 int L=strlen(s1);
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<L;i++)
 if(esteLitera(s1[i]==1)){
              if(s1[i]=='X')s2[i]='A';
              else if(s1[i]=='Y')s2[i]='B';
              else if(s1[i]=='Z')s2[i]='C';
              else s2[i]=s1[i]+3;}
 else s2[i]=s1[i];
 cout<<"Textul criptat este: "<<s2<<endl;
 cout<<"Apasati o tasta pentru a reveni la meniu.";
 getch();
}

void criptMansfield()
{
 system("cls");
 int i,j,k,x=0;
 char rez[200],c[100];
 char a[5]={'A','E','I','O','U'};
 char b[5]={'A','E','I','O','U'};
 char p[5][5]={'A','B','C','D','E',
                 'F','G','H','I','J',
                 'K','L','M','N','O',
                 'P','R','S','T','U',
                 'V','W','X','Y','Z' } ;

  cout<<"        "<<"Criptare Mansfield"<<endl<<endl;
  cout<<"Introduceti textul pentru criptare:";
  cin.get();
  cin.get(c,100);
  strupr(c);
  for ( k=0;k<strlen(c);k++ )
   if ((c[k]>='A')&&(c[k]<='Z'))
    for ( i=0;i<=4;i++ )
     for ( j=0;j<=4;j++ )
      if ( c[k]==p[i][j] ){rez[x]=a[i];
                           x++;
                           rez[x]=b[j];
                           x++;}
        else;
       else{rez[x]=c[k];
            x++;}

  rez[x]=0;
  cout<<rez;
  getch();
}

void decriptTranspozitie()
{
 system("cls");
 char s[101],x[51],y[51];
 int i,j,optiune;
 cout<<"Decriptare transpozitie cu doua jumatati"<<endl<<endl;
 cout<<"Dati textul pentru decriptat:";
 cin.get();
 cin.get(s,100);
 strupr(s);
  if(strlen(s)%2==0){
   for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i+=2)
      cout<<s[i];
    for(j=1;j<strlen(s);j+=2)
        cout<<s[j];
                    }

else if(strlen(s)%2!=0){
 for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i+=2)
     cout<<s[i];
  for(j=1;j<strlen(s);j+=2)
      cout<<s[j];
     cout<<s[j];       }
    cout<<"\n\n\nPentru a reveni la meniu apasati tasta 1!\n";
   cin>>optiune;
  switch (optiune)
 {case (1) : { afisareMeniu(); break; } }
}
int esteLitera(char x)
{
 if((x>='A')&&(x<='Z'))
 return 1;
 else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `esteLitera`is wrong. You declare the function as

```
int esteLitera();
```

Then you try to call it with an argument. Change the declaration to

```
int esteLitera(char);
```

Also, you´re calling `esteLitera` with a boolean argument, not a char:

```
if(esteLitera(s1[i]==1)){
```